# Blazor WebAssembly: Update single row in Data Grid / Table

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I would like to use Data Grid/Table with Virtualize to display list of items. When one user edits data in single row, it should notify others about changes and UI should be updated for every user. Is any way to update only single row without refresh all the list for others client?

Page

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer in **NO** you can't update just a row, and a comprehensive answer that details how to build the infrastructure to do this is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Here's a short precis:

1. You need your data in view services.
2. Your UI components need to subscribe to events in these view services whenever something in a list is updated and needs refreshing.
3. You need to call the `RefreshDataAsync` method on the visualize component from your page to update the row in the component.
4. You should probably be using `ItemProvider` in the Visualize component to minimize list paging.

Ask if you want help on specifics.